# Get MouseWheel Scroll Position in a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, scroll, flowlayoutpanel

I have a FlowLayoutPanel which can be scrolled by the user on the verticle axis. i have the following event handler which is used to see where the user has scrolled to and provides the position number within blocks of 405px:

```
private void ChangedParentFlowPanel_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    int NewPos = e.NewValue;

    int range = (NewPos - 1) / 405 + 1;

    CurrentIndex_Changed = range;
    tCounter.Text = CurrentIndex_Changed.ToString();
}
```

That works just fine and does exactly what i need when the user scrolls using the verticle bar. The problem i have is i need to update tCounter with the same value but this time when the user scrolls using the mouse wheel. I'Ve tried the following but this only ever seems to provide the Y axis value for the location of the mouse when it scrolls and not the location of the scroll itself:

```
private void ChangedParentFlowPanel_Wheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int NewPos = e.Location.Y;
    MessageBox.Show(NewPos.ToString());


    int range = (NewPos - 1) / 405 + 1;

    CurrentIndex_Changed = range;
    tCounter.Text = CurrentIndex_Changed.ToString();
}
```

The question is...how can i get the scroll  position of the scroll in ChangedParentFlowPanel when a mousewheel is used?

Comment: Use the panel's AutoScrollPosition property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by Hans Pasant here's the answer:

```
private void ChangedParentFlowPanel_Wheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int NewPos = Math.Abs(ChangedParentFlowPanel.AutoScrollPosition.Y);

    int range = (NewPos - 1) / 405 + 1;

    CurrentIndex_Changed = range;
    tCounter.Text = CurrentIndex_Changed.ToString();
}
```

Math.Abs because the returned scroll Y value is minus and i need a positive value.